# Why ngdocs only reads from a single directory and not js in multiple directories (am using gulp)?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

All of my js files have documentation, my documentation exists in the following folder structure:

```
myapplication/js/controllers/samplecontroller.js
myapplication/js/directives/sampledirective.js
myapplication/js/main.js
myapplication/js/app.js
```

My gulp task is:

```
gulp.task('ngdocs', [], function () {
  var gulpDocs = require('gulp-ngdocs');
  var options = {
    scripts: ['./controllers/*.js','./directives/*.js'],
    startPage: '/api',
    title: "Awesome Docs",
    titleLink: "/api"
  }  
  return gulp.src('myapplication/js/*.js')
    .pipe(gulpDocs.process(options))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./docs'));
});
```

I notice that the docs generated are only picking up the ones in "main.js" and "app.js". Is there a way to make it such that all the files i have under "/controllers" and "/directives" are picked up too? Or is this not the common practice?

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the recursive operator `**` in the folder structure like this:

```
  return gulp.src('myapplication/js/**/*.js')
```

Comment: you example does not align to the explanation. shouldn't that be   `return gulp.src('myapplication/js/**/*.js')`

Comment: any ideas on how to create a file (.pdf or .doc) with all documentation details rather than a web app?